# How to tell Flexbox "make these divs 100% width unless all of them fit in the same line"?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-item">
        Some text.
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-item">
        Some quite longer, longer, longer text.
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-item">
        Some other text.
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

How can I tell the flexbox container to give all of its children a 100% width unless **all of them** fit in the same line, effectively occupying 33.33% each?

Tried this:

```
.flexbox-item {
    min-width: 33%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

But it's not exactly what I'm looking for, since as soon as 2 items fit in a line, the third one will be wrapped.

**Edit-** Some more info: The expected behaviour of these divs is for them to occupy 100% width on mobile, and then as soon as they all fit in the same line, to have justify-content: space-between work its magic. **Space-between is required**. I can do this in a more specific way with breakpoints but would like to go flexbox all the way.

[Pen here](https://codepen.io/mrmerrick/pen/NpBejG)

Comment: In general, `flexbox` does not replace breakpoints, and in your case you'll need them

Comment: (agree with LGSon) min-width can be used as a breaking points when flex wrap, but it will take elements to next line one by one,  . what you need here is media queries to update the flex values. min-width will remain min-width. % was not the best idea ... pixels maybe for some wrapping effects ...

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but I don't work with CSS everyday so I'm not an expert and imagined there would be an advanced way of doing it I didn't know about. This is easily solved by using breakpoints, but I'll have to be very careful about the divs' content and design around guesswork, which I thought flexbox was meant to take away. Oh well! Thanks!